# Galera Manager web gui for mariadb

Tags: mariadb, galera

I want to create a MariaDB 10.4 multi-master cluster on four Ubuntu 20.04 nodes. As you know Galera manager provides a web GUI interface for the cluster and it's handy for monitoring and add or remove nodes.

But because I am not using Galera Manager on the amazon ec2 platform, I encountered some errors, and here is what I've done:

1- I have ubuntu 20.04 with MariaDB 10.4 as node1.

2- On the node1 server, I have enabled root to log in over ssh.

3- On Galera manager which is on another Ubuntu server, I have imported root ssh keys to node1, so Galera Manager can access node1 server over ssh with root users.

4- On the Galera manager console I have created a cluster as you can see here: [image: Create_cluster]

5- Then I added node1 server to the cluster as you can see here: [image: Add_Node]

6- You can see the complete deployment log as you can see here:[Full Log](https://cloudvyzor.com/logpad/?query&database=sandbox-d77e5f1f60e94a12e364812315f23f27)

7- After node installation finishes node status will become unknown as you can see here:[image: Node_became_unkown]

At this point, you cannot start or stop the node, and as you can see log files are empty! and the whole cluster becomes useless, no matter how many nodes you add they all become unknown.

I know that I can create a multi-master Galera cluster without the Galera manager, but as I mentioned before, I need it for monitoring and scaling.

If we cannot fix this problem, please tell me is there any alternative for managing and monitoring the Galera cluster through a web interface other than ClusterControl which is so expensive??

Comment: if you achieve this I love to read about

Comment: Nope!! Even the Galera cluster team didn't answer me. They told me: Okay, give us some details. But once I did, they didn't answer my emails at all! I think they couldn't fix the problem too!! why they release untested software? That's what I want to know!

Comment: Ok, maybe is a comercial strategy, they point to the aws , but they keep a space for on premise paid solutions like clustercontrol